# BigtableConfiguration v BigtableOptions when running Bigtable emulator

Tags: java, scala, hbase, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I have some working code. It uses a [BigtableConfiguration](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-client/javadoc/com/google/cloud/bigtable/hbase/BigtableConfiguration) object to return to get a connection to Bigtable, like so:

```
var connection = BigtableConfiguration.connect("myProject", "myCluster")
```

The connection returned is of type `com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.Connection`.

I understand that there is now a Bigtable emulator for use locally and I wish to use it in my tests. So I'm trying to understand how to leverage it.

It seems that in order to take advantage of auto-configuration based on the emulator env var, you need to use another config-type class called `BigtableOptions`, like so:

```
  val options = new BigtableOptions.Builder()
    .setProjectId("myProject")
    .setInstanceId("myCluster")
    .setUserAgent("whatever")
    .build()
```

This class has [the logic](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/blob/master/bigtable-client-core-parent/bigtable-client-core/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/config/BigtableOptions.java#L241) to detect the emulator. However, I can't pass it to my existing `BigtableConfiguration.connect()` method.

So I'm confused as to how I can use this new `BigtableOptions` class with my existing code. I can go down the route of using a [BigtableSession](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-client/javadoc/com/google/cloud/bigtable/grpc/BigtableSession) object, but this means a re-write.

I want to leverage the auto-configuration promised by the emulator if the env var is set, but right now I'm considering abandoning that in favour of an answer like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38577163/how-to-connect-to-a-running-bigtable-emulator-from-java).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cloud Bigtable 0.9.4 client should just work with the emulator if the environment variable is set.  See [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/blob/bigtable-client-0.9.4/bigtable-client-core-parent/bigtable-client-core/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/config/BigtableOptions.java#L199), in the BigtableOptions source code, for the implementation details.

If that doesn't work for you, let's please continue the discussion on a [github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-client/issues).

Comment: All works now. So it seems `BigtableOptions` is just used under the hood in some way, and I don't need to configure it explicitly. Thanks for the help.