# How to connect to Bigtable emulator from node.js client?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

Is there anyway to connect to a Bigtable emulator running on localhost using the node.js client? I get this if I try to do so

```
Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SS
```

Is there a similar configuration like [the one in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38577163/how-to-connect-to-a-running-bigtable-emulator-from-java)?

```
conf.set(BigtableOptionsFactory.BIGTABLE_USE_PLAINTEXT_NEGOTIATION, true);
```

Comment: Did you run `BIGTABLE_EMULATOR_HOST=$(gcloud beta emulators bigtable env-init)` before as explained in [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/emulator#using_the_emulator) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/bigtable/0.11.x/Bigtable#Bigtable)?

Comment: @GuillemXercavins I did manually set the system's environment variable BIGTABLE_EMULATOR_HOST to localhost:8086 (or 127.0.0.1:8086). I'm on Windows so the above command is not availablle.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you should use the following command:

```
set BIGTABLE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8086
```

from the same command prompt window where you intend to run Bigtable client code.

To set this environment variable globally, use:

```
setx BIGTABLE_EMULATOR_HOST "localhost:8086"
```

close the command prompt, open again and run Bigtable client code.

Comment: I did set the environment variable correctly because I could use cbt command with the emulator instance. The problem is most likely with how the client is demanding an SSL connection from the emulator.

Comment: when bigtable client connects to emulator it dont use SSL. Can you paste sample code that you are using?